# File q.sty not found Latex Linux

Tags: latex, xelatex

I'm trying to compile this document (Plasmati Graduate CV) I got with xelatex and it complains about not finding q.sty. For all the other missing files I could just Google or search in the Synaptic Package Manager but I guess with the short filename it's hard to find. Anybody know which package it could be in?

Comment: That's very random. We would need some code to show the class, and where to find it. From there one can search to find `q.sty`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case this is still not resolved, your missing files are in the texlive package in Ubuntu:

```
apt-get install texlive
```